# Pandas Pivot table returns empty data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I'm having problem creating a pivot table using a filtered dataframe, but when i print it it returns an empty dataframe

I tried separating the filtering of the Dt from the generation of the pivot table, still gives the same results

the filtered dataframe and the result

```
print(df[(df['Texto'].str.contains("Baja") == False) & (df['Texto'].str.contains("aplica") == False)])

          N doc.  Div. Cla  Fecha doc.    CT        Importe en ML                                        Texto  Activo fijo       Cuenta
0    100248075.0   1.0  SA  03.04.2019  70.0               22.727  Actualizacion M.Obra Mes Sept-18 Sist.Geog.   20003358.0  123134001.0
1    100248076.0   1.0  AB  03.04.2019  75.0              -22.727  Actualizacion M.Obra Mes Sept-18 Sist.Geog.   20003358.0  123134001.0
2    100248078.0   1.0  SA  03.04.2019  70.0               22.727  Actualizacion M.Obra Mes Sept-18 Sist.Geog.   20003358.0  123134001.0
3    100248229.0   NaN  SA  05.04.2019  70.0              342.667                         CIERRE PY 201/NZ-555    1018875.0  123134001.0
4    100248230.0   NaN  SA  05.04.2019  70.0               92.518                         CIERRE PY 201/NZ-555   20003447.0  123134001.0
..           ...   ...  ..         ...   ...                  ...                                          ...          ...          ...
410  100251321.0   NaN  AA  30.04.2019  75.0               -1.057     Aplicación Prov. Depreciación 201/NZ-583   20003461.0  123134001.0
411  100251322.0   NaN  AA  30.04.2019  75.0                -1.49     Aplicación Prov. Depreciación 201/NZ-605    3007473.0  123134002.0
412  100251323.0   NaN  AA  30.04.2019  75.0              -31.751     Aplicación Prov. Depreciación 201/NZ-542    3007475.0  123134002.0
413  100251324.0   NaN  AA  30.04.2019  75.0              -29.929     Aplicación Prov. Depreciación 201/NZ-555    1018876.0  123134001.0
414  100251325.0   NaN  AA  30.04.2019  75.0               -22.31     Aplicación Prov. Depreciación 201/NZ-553   20003470.0  123134001.0
```

the pivot table and the result:

```
pivot_add = df[(df['Texto'].str.contains("Baja") == False) & (df['Texto'].str.contains("aplica") == False)].pivot_table(
        index='Cuenta', values='       Importe en ML', aggfunc='sum')

print(pivot_add)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Comment: Showing some sample data would be helpful to reproduce your issues.  [Creating a Minimal Reproduceable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: your code worked as expected with sample data

Comment: yeah, i have two other pivot tables that work but this one won't generate the values, if i try it with just one condition still returns an empty data frame